# Is there a qualifier for smallestWidth LESS than some value?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing an app which has different layout and value files for various screens, then I meet a problem: The smallestWidth qualifier only checks if the device smallestWidth is GREATER than indicated value.

This is troublesome when I have below folder structure:

```
res/layout-port-mdpi
res/layout-sw720dp
res/layout-sw720dp-port
res/layout-sw720dp-land
```

In this case, on a `mdpi` `sw720` `port` device, Android will use `res/layout-port-mdpi` rather than `res/layout-sw720dp-port` which I really want to use. The `res/layout-port-mdpi` is for smaller phones.

Is there a way to indicate smallestWidth **LESS** than like 719dp, or should I need to create `res/layout-sw720dp-port-mdpi` and for all other dpis? It sounds so stupid.

Thank you for the kind answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The res/layout-port-mdpi is for smaller phones.

No, it is not. It is for portrait devices with medium density screens. It stipulates nothing with respect to size.

> In this case, on a mdpi sw720 port device, Android will use res/layout-port-mdpi rather than res/layout-sw720dp-port which I really want to use.

No. `-sw720dp` is a stronger criterion than is `-mdpi`, so for a device that is `-sw720dp` *and* `-mdpi` *and* is held in portrait, `res/layout-sw720dp-port` should be used.

> Is there a way to indicate smallestWidth LESS than like 719dp

Not really. Android will use a resource set that does not have any `-swNNNdp` value if the device's value is lower than any such resource set you use.

> should I need to create res/layout-sw720dp-port-mdpi and for all other dpis?

No.

For example, if your objective is to have some layouts used specifically for `-sw720dp` devices and other layouts used for smaller devices, with some different layouts for landscape for each size, your directories would be:

- `res/layout-sw720dp-land/` for `-sw720dp` devices in landscape orientation
- `res/layout-sw720dp/` for `-sw720dp` devices not in landscape orientation
- `res/layout-land/` for smaller than `-sw720dp` devices held in landscape
- `res/layout/` for smaller than `-sw720dp` devices not in landscape orientation

Have one of every layout in `res/layout/`, and override those layouts in resource sets with more constraints only where needed.

Comment: Nice. Futhermore, I also modified other port/land to w<N>dp and h<N>dp, which works great on various screens. Thank you!